# How does one measure the brightness of a laser?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I'm doing an experiment which requires that I measure the intensity of light of a laser. I'm a beginner at physics, so I don't really know how the candela works. Could someone explain what instruments and scientific process one would go about measuring the brightness of a laser pointer?

Thank you!

Comment: Please give us some context; tell us about the experiment, and why you need to measure the intensity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually laser power is measured in W or mW by shining the laser onto a commercially available optical power meter.

Comment: Thank you! Now, what if your school was incredibly underfunded and... doesn't have an optical power meter? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: For very low laser powers you could use a camera to tell relative power levels to some degree. Can you explain why you need to measure laser power? What is your laser wavelength and estimated power?

Comment: @nebbie you need some kind of calibrated photodetector. The cheapest thing (other than borrowing one) would probably be to buy a bare calibrated photodiode and wire it up yourself. But if you know anyone in a physics department or anyone doing any kind of optics experimentation, ask if you can borrow theirs.

Comment: Yes, building your own with some electronics know-how is a good idea. You’ll probably need a lens to focus the light onto a small photodiode active aperture.

Comment: If you use a lens to focus the light, then you also need to account for how much light the lens reflects, which might make it difficult to measure the emitted power.